# Appending column to a dynamically changing / updating text

Tags: shell

I have the below script written.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter your SR number : " SR
echo -e "$SR\t$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" >> /tmp/cases.txt

awk 'BEGIN{printf("%-5s%-20s%-20s\n","#","Case Number","Date Opened")}{printf("%-5s%-20s%-20s\n",NR,$1,$2,$3)}' /tmp/cases.txt
```

The output of this in cases.txt file is

```
[root@centOS ~]# cat /tmp/cases.txt
1234567890      2017-03-24
2345678901      2017-03-24
```

But the output of the script is:

```
#    Case Number         Date Opened
1    1234567890          2017-03-24
2    2345678901          2017-03-24
```

If I try appending the awk output to cases.txt file, then it prints the column names everytime I run the script.

My goal is, this script will be meant to keep a track of all incoming cases. The script will be run everytime a new case is opened. And it updates the cases.txt file. I would like to have the cases.txt file to have **#** **Case** **Number** and **Date** **opened** columns, where **#** increments every time a new value comes in. This partially works with the above script, but not the way I want it.

Any help please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f='/tmp/cases.txt'
[ -s "$f" ] || printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' '#' 'Case Number' 'Date Opened' > "$f"
n=$(wc -l < "$f")
read -p "Enter your SR number: " SR
printf '%d\t%d\t%s\n' "$n" "$SR" "$(date)" >> "$f"
```